# self.method = environ['REQUEST_METHOD'].upper() KeyError: 'REQUEST_METHOD' while setting up django server on EC2 using uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi

I am getting a

[image]

when I hit `http://ec2-X-YZ-ABC-EFG.compute-1.amazonaws.com/admin`.

I am quite sure there is nothing wrong with my Django app since, the app is empty ie. I just created the app using `django-admin startproject tempo` with just this change--`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`, so that it accepts requests from any IPs.

Since this is a dev server and contains no data I have allowed requests from any hosts. Here are my **inbound rules**,

```
Ports   Protocol    Source
 80       tcp      0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
 22       tcp      0.0.0.0/0, ::/0  
 443      tcp      0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```

Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/tempo`

```
upstream tempo-server {
    server   unix:///home/ubuntu/tempo/tempo.sock;
}
server {
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/tempo/error.log;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/tempo/access.log;
    listen 80;
    server_name X.YX.ABC.DEF;
    location = /media/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/tempo/media;
    }
    location / {
        include        /etc/uwsgi/sites/uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass    tempo-server;
    }
}
```

and here is my `uwsgi.ini` file

```
[uwsgi]
chdir           = /home/ubuntu/tempo
module          = tempo.wsgi
home            = /home/ubuntu/seatr/venv-seatr
master          = true
processes       = 10
socket          = /home/ubuntu/tempo/tempo.sock
chmod-socket    = 777
vacuum          = true
```

Also, uwsgi starts with no errors, the .sock file is also created successfully.

The nginx `error.log` shows:

```
2019/04/04 20:03:48 [error] 30261#30261: *9 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 129.219.8.129, server: X.YZ.ABC.DEF, request: "GET /admin HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/ubuntu/tempo/tempo.sock:", host: "ec2-X-YZ-ABC-DEF.compute-1.amazonaws.com"
```

PS: my sites-enabled (soft-linked) contains only this `tempo` file, the sites-available contains a couple of files.

I have read this problem being asked at multiple places, but no answers:

[here](https://djbook.ru/forum/topic/3286/)
[here](http://librelist.com/browser/flask/2013/4/15/keyerror-request-method-when-running-getting-started-application-on-uwsgi/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My **uwsgi_params** file was completely empty. As a result **nginx** was not able to send the parameters like "*REQUEST_METHOD*" and thus the above error.

My **uwsgi_params** file is as follows:

```
uwsgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
uwsgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
uwsgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
uwsgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
uwsgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
uwsgi_param PATH_INFO $document_uri;
uwsgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
uwsgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
uwsgi_param HTTPS $https if_not_empty;
uwsgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
uwsgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
uwsgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
uwsgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
```

Comment: What I like to do is add a file called uwsgi_param place all your parameters here and then on the nginx just place 
```
include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
```