# How to restrict media files of django project via nginx without dedicated server

Tags: django, nginx, uwsgi, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am running a Django project in a docker container. Uwsgi is my chosen protocol. Nginx is acting as a reverse proxy.

I am able to restrict django sites for users based `user.is_authenticated()`.
I am **not able** to restrict media and static files for not authenticated users as they get served directly from the filesystem.

I do not have a second, dedicated server which only purpose is to identify and authenticate users. As I already have the functionality within my django project, I want to use this.

My nginx configuration:

```
events{}

daemon off;


http {
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    upstream django {
        server unix:///tmp/nginx/diplab.sock;
    }

    server {
    listen 8080;

    location = /accounts/check-authenticated {
        internal;
        uwsgi_pass              django;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
        }

    location /static {
        alias /vol/web/static;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        }

    location /media {
        alias /vol/web/media;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        auth_request /accounts/check-authenticated;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        }

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass django;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

My Django Setup of the view which has the purpose to authenticate a user (200) or not (401).

```
# urls.py
app_name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path('check-authenticated/', views.is_authenticated_view, name="check-authenticated"),
    path('login/', views.UserLoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]


# views.py
def is_authenticated_view(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    return HttpResponse(status=401)
```

The error that shows up is fairly deep inside Djangos core:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/myproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 130, in __call__
    request = self.request_class(environ)
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/myproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 78, in __init__
    self.method = environ["REQUEST_METHOD"].upper()
KeyError: 'REQUEST_METHOD'
```

The `error.log` of nginx shows the following:

```
2022/12/06 17:42:27 [error] 194#194: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /media/myname/compound_structures/1cf10238af0.png HTTP/1.1", subrequest: "/accounts/check-authenticated", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/nginx/diplab.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/toolbox/"
2022/12/06 17:42:27 [error] 194#194: *1 auth request unexpected status: 502 while sending to client, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /media/myname/compound_structures/1cf10238af0.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/toolbox/"
```

I tried to add the `REQUEST_METHOD` plus some other variables like this, but without being successful - still same error.

```
location = /accounts/check-authenticated {
    internal;
    uwsgi_pass              django;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header        REQUEST_METHOD GET;
    proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    proxy_set_header X-Original-Remote-Addr $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
    }
```

I am by far no expert in terms of nginx and appreciate any help! This is the approach I found first. I'd be happy if you recommend me another approach if you are not able to help me with this one.

### Edit 1

As Elgin Cahangirov suggested, I now include the uwsgi_params to the location block like this:

```
location = /accounts/check-authenticated {
    internal;
    uwsgi_pass              django;
    proxy_pass_request_body off;
    proxy_set_header        Content-Length "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Original-URI $request_uri;
    include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
    }
```

I think it definitely helped on my journey, as one of many errors is fixed, but sadly the images still do not show up.
uwsgi:

```
172.19.0.1 - - [07/Dec/2022:08:33:33 +0000] "GET /media/myname/compound_structures/1cf10238af0.png HTTP/1.1" 500 186 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
[pid: 219|app: 0|req: 19/19] 172.19.0.1 () {52 vars in 936 bytes} [Wed Dec  7 08:33:33 2022] GET /media/myname/compound_structures/1cf10238af0.png => generated 0 bytes in 1 msecs (HTTP/1.1 301) 6 headers in 239 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
```

nginx error.log

```
2022/12/07 08:33:33 [error] 195#195: *30 auth request unexpected status: 301 while sending to client, client: 172.19.0.1, server: , request: "GET /media/myname/compound_structures/1cf10238af0.png HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55524354/self-method-environrequest-method-upper-keyerror-request-method-while) answer your question?

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion! Yes, it helped and including uwsgi_params makes completely sense. Sadly there is more to it than that I suppose. I edited my question.